# Why can't I "unpack" a tuple in pdb?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

How can I do this in a pythonic way?

```
x = (1,2,3)
a = x[0]
b = x[1]
c = x[2]
```

I tried this, which didn't work:

```
a,b,c = x
```

**Update**: Apparently it works outside `pdb` but not inside. Sorry for only trying inside. This is what didn't work for me:

```
>>> import pdb
>>> pdb.set_trace()
--Return--
> <stdin>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb) x=(1,2,3)
(Pdb) a,b,c=x
(Pdb) print(a)
*** NameError: name 'a' is not defined
(Pdb)
```

So the issue is solved, and I'll make sure not to try new things in the debugger next time. But why didn't it work?

Comment: a,b,c = x works already.

Comment: What error did you get when you tried ```a,b,c = x```?

Comment: What interpreter version are you running?

Comment: @myildirim Sorry, I've updated the question

Comment: @wnnmaw "name a is not defined". I updated the question

Comment: @StoryTeller Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Comment: c is a command in pdb.

Comment: @user189 Thanks! I changed names for the variables a and c, and now it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with variable names. `a` and `c` are [commands](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands) in pdb. Specifically, they are for `continue` and `args`. By changing those variable names, it will work.

```
>>> import pdb
>>> pdb.set_trace()
--Return--
> <stdin>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb) x=(1,2,3)
(Pdb) first,second,third=x
(Pdb) print(first)
1
```